# Continuous random varaible: If X and Y are continuous random variables What are the conditions required for X/Y to be a continuous RV?

Tags: probability, continuity, random-variables

If there are two continuous random variables $X$ and $Y$. 
What are the additional conditions required on $X$ and $Y$ under which ratio of these random variables $\frac{X}{Y}$ is also a continuous random variable?

I know that divide by zero events should have zero probability and  Y should not be scaled version of $X$, in which case ratio is constant. 
I tried searching real analysis books. Sum and composition of two random variables is clear to me but I am still confused about ratio.

What are the other conditions these two random variables should satisfy such that $\frac{X}{Y}$ is also a continuous random variable?

Comment: Whats a continuous random variable?

Comment: There are two conflicting definitions of continuous random variables. However, with either of those definitions $X/Y$ is continuous if $X$ and $Y$ are independent continuous random variables.

Comment: Without independence $X=|Y|$ gives a  counterexample where the ratio is not  constant.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thank you, sir. Independence helps me move forward with my problem.  Can you please point me to some reference where I can find some proof related to this.

Comment: you said that "Sum and composition of two random variables is clear to me", could you answer this question please, X-Y is a continuous RV? Thanks